# Any reason for being called 'Chicken Fingers', given it's not made from fingers of chicken at all?

Tags: etymology

Originally, I thought Chicken Fingers is made from the fingers of chickens. But after I saw this [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_fingers), it's actually made from "the pectoralis minor muscles of the animal".

So, I'm curious why it's called **Chicken Fingers** given it has nothing to do with fingers at all?

Comment: Many foods called "fingers" are approximately the shape and size of human fingers.

Comment: As @StoneyB says - fish fingers (aka fish sticks), lady fingers (small oblong sponge cakes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things which are long and narrow are called *fingers* in English, from [ladyfinger cookies/biscuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladyfinger_(biscuit)) to the [Finger Lakes](https://www.fingerlakes.org/). OALD includes a a subordinate meaning of *[finger](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/finger_1)* as

> **finger (of something)** a long narrow piece of bread, cake, land, etc.
>
> > a finger of toast
> >     chocolate fingers

In British English, a similar food made from fish is know as *[fish fingers](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/fish-finger)*, though they are called *fish sticks* in North America.

Note that the term *finger food* is for a different and unrelated concept, however, and refers to food of any shape that is portioned into small pieces intended to be picked up and eaten with the fingers.